# How to use a string to reference a combobox name

Tags: c#

I have a table populated with comboboxes like this:

```
rowCombobox.Name = "rowCombobox" + c;
```

where c is the number of the row that it resides in.

Is it possible to use a string later to reference that combobox as I am looping through the rows of the table, much like I named the combobox just in reverse?

For example:

```
String comboname = "rowCombobox" + c;
```

If so how would I implement that?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Comboboxes exit in most .NET UI frameworks (WinForms, WPF, some web frameworks, the modern Windows stuff). You don't specify which. I'm going to guess WinForms. In WinForms, there is a controls collection called `Controls`. If you wanted to find the same control (it's not clear exactly what you are asking), you could use `Controls.Where(c => c.Name == "rowCombobox" + c).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Flydog57 I did try your suggestion.  Controls does not contain a definition for where

Comment: Try `using System.Linq` at the top

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can references to control by his name, if you not changing name in runtime, for example:

```
string comboBoxName = "comboBox1";
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)this.Controls[comboBoxName];
```

Is valid if you **expilicitly** sets name of control
also you can call control from field in you Form class

Comment: should the second line read ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox).this.Controls[comboBoxName];?

Comment: @LorenZimmer - Yes, it should. This approach is generally a bad idea. There are better ways to do this.

Comment: @Enigmativity do you have any suggestions or examples you could share?  This suggestion seems to return a null result.

Comment: @Enigmativity, sorry didn't notice

Comment: @LorenZimmer - The approach here does work, but it's not the best way to go. It's too easy to write code that returns a `null` as you have found out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my preferred way to loop through a set of controls:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    ComboBox[] comboboxes = new ComboBox[]
    {
        combobox1, combobox2, combobox3, combobox4,
        combobox5, combobox6, combobox7, combobox8,
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < comboboxes.Length; i++)
    {
        // Do something with each `comboboxes[i]`
    }
}
```

This is strongly-typed and localized to the method that you're using them in. If you change any of the controls in a way that breaks this code then you get compile-time errors so you can quickly fix it.

Now, if you're making controls on the fly then just add each `ComboBox` to a `List<ComboBox>` and use that to iterate through.

Comment: How would you deal with a situation where you weren't sure how many comboboxes were required?

Comment: @LorenZimmer - Then you're making them on the fly so you just build the `List<ComboBox>` like I suggested. Can you elaborate on specifically what your situation is?